# Build error "No such module 'MLKitVision'" when building Flutter app for iOS with latest CocoaPods (1.15.1)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods

When I try to build my Flutter (Flutter 3.16.9, channel stable) app I receive the above mentioned error:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'MLKitVision'
/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/mobile_scanner-3.5.7/ios/Classes/MobileScanner.swift:10:7
```

I have the latest CocoaPods version installed, which is `1.15.1` as of today.

My build steps are

```
flutter clean &&
 flutter pub get &&
 flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs &&
 flutter run
```

as well as

```
cd ios/
rm -rf Podfile.lock &&
  rm -rf Pods &&
  pod repo update &&
  pod cache clean --all &&
  pod deintegrate &&
  pod setup &&
  pod install --repo-update
```

With these steps I could get through errors like this in the past, this seems to be different today, though.

Does anybody experience the same, or maybe has found a solution to this?

Comment: Did you check this answer? :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77419102/19807154

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It seems like the `mobile_scanner` package is not compatible with the latest CocoaPods version. https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/issues/953

Comment: did you tried upgrading to 4.0.0? we actually have the same issue

Comment: I did, see the linked Github issue in the `mobile_scanner` repository. A clean flutter project with added dependency 4.0.0 results in the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to CocoaPods 1.15.2 for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Same error for all external frameworks, like ZoomVideoSDK and TerraiOS. New cocoapods version cannot be used for Flutter pod installation if you have any external framework.

Hopefully it will be soon resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).